# emacsclient crashes on start

Tags: emacsclient, emacs-daemon, doom, persp-mode

I use doom emacs. Starting emacs normally works just fine.

Having an emacs daemon and trying to use `emacsclient -c` causes the following error:

```
*ERROR*: Symbol’s function definition is void: persp-mode-start-and-remove-from-make-frame-hook
```

I am using emacs 27.1

Comment: "Crashes" would mean that the client process has died, leaving no window/frame.  Is that what you mean?  (Also: where does the error get displayed?)

Comment: yes. the error gets displayed in the terminal I started emacsclient with

Comment: https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/4025 this issue on doom is the exact same issue I have